# Django custom URL missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following view (empty for test) :

```
from .forms import Form_Step_1

def register(request, step):
    print(step)
```

In my urls.py I have :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('register', register, name='register'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('register?step=<int:step>/', register, name='register'),
]
```

The `register` and `register/` works well. But if I go to `register?step=1` I have the following error :

```
register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using a bad practice of using a URL routing in django.
This is more cleaner and working:
`path('register/step/<int:step>/', register, name='register')`

Answer (score 1):

The `?step=1` part is *not* part of the path, this is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). This is encoded in the `request.GET` as a `QueryDict`, a dictionary-like object.

The path thus should look like:

```
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
```

and in the view, you obtain the data with:

```
from .forms import Form_Step_1

def register(request):
    print(request.GET['step'])
    # …
```